# how to add Continue String Sign like "..." in TextView?

Tags: android, textview

if i add string in a TextView for example,

```
this is my string
```

and TextView max length is 4

It should look like in activity `this...` or `t...` that means string continue sign at the end of assigned string if string size is bigger than Max length.

Can any one guide me what should i do or i will have to manually add "..." at the end of string through programming.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just realised that `this is my string` contains solely keywords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following for your TextViews:

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: For TextViews singleLine is not true by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use singleLine property of TextView:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```